# Occasionally when calling setImageResource on FAB no image at all is displayed

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I've got a FAB that I'm changing the image of with each button press.

So in the xml: `android:src="@drawable/start_img"`

Then in the button press function:

```
if (start_state) {
    ...
    start_state = false;
    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.second_img);
else {
    ...
    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.start_img);
    start_state = true;
}
```

But occasionally (I cannot find any sort of pattern), no image will be displayed on the FAB at all. This state remains until I reload the fragment.

I have no clue how this can be happening. Calling `fab.setImageResource` only happens in those two circumstances, and it's not like I'm dynamically creating the image or something, they're fixed. Why would it vanish.

I cannot show all the code of the app.

Comment: Without seeing more of the code, the only reasonable thing to guess is that `start_state` isn't set to the value you expect it to be. Why not add some logs in your code to make sure `start_state` is what it should be when you reach that part of the code?

Comment: It does not matter what `start_state` is, none of the code is setting the image to an empty image.

Comment: If `start_state` is true, and the image is already `R.drawable.second_img`, then nothing will appear to happen

Comment: You need to read what I'm saying more carefully. I'm saying that *literally no image at all* will be displayed. As if something had called `fab.setImageResource(None)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really figured it out but have an idea of what is causing it.

I call `hide()` on the FAB when opening the keyboard for a specific EditText. Afterwards when the keyboard closes (and I call `show()`) and I press the FAB (which should switch the displayed image), it switches to displaying no image at all.

But when I comment out the `.hide()` line, everything works (bizarrely)! Meaning I touch the edittext, then touch outside the finish the interaction, then touch the FAB and the image is switched.

Note I have to go through this sequence of first editing the EditText (which causes a call to `hide()`), then pressing the FAB to get the behaviour of the FAB image disappearing.